# where to place the mutagen folder

Tags: python, django, mutagen

I'm making an app in a cloud9 workspace and I need to import mutagen. I used the command:

```
$ hg clone https://bitbucket.org/lazka/mutagen
```

as they say in the docs. The thing is that I want to import it in my views file without having to write a very long path. Where should I place the mutagen folder so I can import it the same way I import the 'os' and 'sys' libraries?

By that I mean:

import os
import sys

Sorry for the absolutely dumb question, but this is wrecking my nerves.

Answer (score 0):

Case closed.

In case someone else is struggling to install python libraries, if you have pip installed, just run:

```
~ sudo pip install mutagen
```